# Html5: add image to a parent div and keep the child div images visible

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a HTML5 code. It has a parent div, and two child div. The parent div takes the whole page and each child div takes half a page. I add some images to the left div and some to the right div. Now I need to add an image to the parent div and keep the images on both left and right child divs visible, i. e I want all images super imposed and visubale. 
What is the easiest way of doing this?

Code is like this:

```
<div id="parent"... >
    <div id="leftChild">... </div>
    <div id="rightChild">... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put the image to the parent div using background-image css property?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.

Comment: I can add background image to children and it shows that but looks like children cover parent and its background image is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? 
http://moody.es/nons/kek.html

View page source to see the code.

The parent image has `position: absolute;` and I've the set the children's `<img>` to have `z-index: 1;`. When using z-index, the element in question must be positioned, hence the `position: relative;`

Comment: Ok, I tried making a document, check the link in the post.

Comment: Thanks it is almost what I want but the parent image is in the back while I want it to be in front.

Comment: Simple misunderstanding. Just switch it so the parent image is z-index: 1, and remove z-index from the children, then.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing you may need to make parent container relative or you can keep it as it is!

```css
#parent{  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   background-image: url("http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/health_and_science/science/2015/07/150730_SCI_Cecil_lion.jpg.CROP.promo-xlarge2.jpg");
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 9;
}
#leftChild{
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBUBNygUQANzDPmF45jMi81XQ-nJ70Zw4LGvfpvpTLehLNjWZK8w");
  
    z-index: 0;
}
#rightChild{
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMc12mb4F7OWtwX_r9Sry0SOQgme7GUwXTHVhIipN2WkCWpGZnNQ");
  
  z-index: 0;
}
#parent, #leftChild, #rightChild{
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"... ></div>
    <div id="leftChild">... </div>
    <div id="rightChild">... </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I need the parent background to be front and children images to be back, is it possible?

Comment: Remove opacity if you need to!

Comment: Can you explain where should I remove  opacity?

Comment: #parent that's the only opacity being applied!

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer, the earlier answer resolved my issue so I accepted it.